# Case statement to bucket amounts into categories

Tags: mysql, sql, presto

If I want to create a case statement that buckets column values into one new column how can I do this without multiple case statements?

```
ID | Amount
B     200
W     300
B     300
W     20
```

etc.

Ouput would be grouping by ID and sum of amount for that ID have a new column that buckets them into a category but in one case statement?

```
ID | Amount | Bucket
B     600     >= 500 
W     320     >=0 and <=500
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
select id, sum(amount) as amount,
       (case when sum(amount) >= 0 and sum(amount) < = 500
             then '>= 0 and <= 500' 
             when sum(amount) > 500 
             then '> 500' 
        end) as Bucket
from table t
group by id;
```